# Are open \newwriter files closed when LaTeX exits prematurely with errors?

Tags: external-files, filesystem-access

I am writing a package that needs to write at various times to an external file.  For that I am using the `\newwrite\mywriter` and `\immediate\openout\mywriter` method.  I know to use `\closeout` when done with the file, and I do this.  What I am wondering:  **Does LaTeX close open files, if the process exits prematurely with errors before `\closeout` is reached?**  If it doesn't (and I think it doesn't), is there something I should do in my code to make it safer in this case, and is there something I can do to close the files before I run LaTeX again?

Comment: What makes you think the file is left open?

Comment: @Werner - Newbie concern.  Nothing more.  I haven't actually faced this situation yet.  So far, my simple tests of writing out a LaTeX code file and `\input`ing it later have worked fine.  I just have been doing a lot of Python scripting lately, where, though the garbage collection is pretty robust, it is still not a good idea to leave files open.  `try ... finallly` constructs and the like are great for cleanup, but we don't seem to have such things in LaTeX.  I shall not be so hesitant to drill into TeX source the next time I encounter such an input/output question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The source of TeX tells differently from your belief.

See modules 1332 and 1333 in `tex.web`. Only files open for *input* are not closed.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the look under the hood ... and for your patience with a newbie.  (Warning: newbie taking the bait ...) so, I wonder what is different about files open for input.

Comment: @celticflute Since the premature exit (fatal error or user's choice) can happen at an arbitrary nesting level of `\input`, it's quite hard to go back, but it's quite probable that the operating system will take care of the issue.

Comment: Ah, got it.  OK, I shall have faith in the OS and move on to creating a useful product (a package for building a Celtic music tunebook, BTW).  Thanks again.